# Estou fazendo o jogo Nightmares da Unity e no script do playerMovement meu personagem simplesmente não rotaciona olhando para o mouse

Tags: c#, unity3d, jogos, unity-5

Este é meu código, agradeço desde já pela ajuda.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    //velocidade do jogador

    public float speed = 6f;

    //vetor responsavel pelo movimento
    Vector3 movement;

    //responsavel pela transicao da animacao
    Animator anim;

    //responsavel pela fisica do objeto
    Rigidbody playerRigidbody;

    //mascara de chao
    int floorMask;

    //inf para raycast
    float camRayLength = 100f;

    void Awake()
    {
        //atribuir a mascara da camada
        floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Floor");

        //atribuir as referencias

        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        playerRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }

    void FixedUpdate() //movimentacao do jogador
    {

        float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        Move(h, v);
        Turning();
        Animating(h, v);

    }

    void Move(float h, float v)
    {
        //determina o movimento
        movement.Set(h, 0f, v);

        //normaliza o movimento
        movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        //efetua o movimento no personagem
        playerRigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);
    }

    void Turning() //raio da camera que cria um ponto no floorquad a partir do ponteiro do mouse
    {
        Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        RaycastHit floorHit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(camRay, out floorHit, camRayLength, floorMask))//sua camray, retorno, raio da camray, mascara do chao 
        {

            Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;
            playerToMouse.y = 0f;

            Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerToMouse); //rotacao do player pro mouse
            playerRigidbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);

        }

    }

    void Animating(float h, float v)
    {
        bool walking = h != 0f || v != 0f; //checando se o player se movimenta ou nao
        anim.SetBool("IsWalking", walking);


    }
}
```

Comment: Acredito que você poderia testar o que está funcionando, se a captura da posição do mouse está pegando, também uma boa solução seria utilizar o 

    transform.Rotate(0,-1.2f,0) 

Ele faz o objeto rotacionar, eu utilizo ele, então pode ser que funcione para você também.

Comment: Tudo está funcionando menos a captura do mouse na tela, o personagem deveria olhar para o cursor